# Best IPC for Raspberry Pi, POSIX MQ vs, Message Broker protocol

Tags: linux, posix, ipc, raspberry-pi3, messagebroker

I'm currently developing a Software for Raspian which should be decentralized. There should be Processes for getting sensor data, a process for running motor controllers, a process for controlling environmental variables, a Webserver for a WEB GUI, a Database Process, a Login Process and something like a main process for putting everything together. It should be possible to start interactions via the WEB GUI, probably Remote Procedure calls. I just started with POSIX Message Queues, but I'm not sure if it is the right thing for me. I read about Message Brokers like Rabbit MQ, Mosquitto, ZeroMQ and so on. What would be the advantage of using one of these in comparison to the Posix MQ? Would it be the better approach using one of these? With Posix I have to program the Message Broker myself? Are there already implementations for Posix MQ Broker? So far it is planned to have the Message Queue run just internally rather than connect several devices.